# How to get full image URL from the Zoho Inventory via the API?

Tags: image, api, inventory, zoho

I got this document from the api response:
`https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/items/{item_id}`

```
"documents":[
{
"source_formatted":"Desktop",
"can_send_in_mail":false,
"file_name":"Personalization-vantage-technology.jpg",
"file_type":"jpg",
"file_size_formatted":"40.2 KB",
"attachment_order":1,
"source":"desktop",
"document_id":"1877812000004113075",
"file_size":"41179",
"alter_text":""
}
],
```

The question is how can I get the full image URL? I would like to display the image on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Zoho.
This API returns an image, remember to use the ***item_id***

```
Greetings from Zoho Inventory!

We would like to inform you that in order to retrieve image of an item you can use the below API request.

https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/items/{item_id}/image?authtoken=XXXXX&organization_id=XXXXX

METHOD: GET


Hope this helps. 

If you have further queries, kindly feel free to get back to us.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an answer to this but as of 2022 you must pass the oauth in the header, not as a parameter in the request URL

curl https://inventory.zoho.com/api/v1/items/3605392000000076013/image?organization_id=55555555 -H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.63ed321edc13318ca200ca.28e9b7be958f1867f0c69"

This returns the image file, not the url to the image.